# Sphinx SPH_MATCH_ALL,SPH_MATCH_PHRASE,SPH_MATCH_BOOLEAN,SPH_MATCH_ALL and SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2?

Tags: php, sphinx

I am new to Sphinx Search. How to use this Matching modes in PHP?

Example:

```
   SPH_MATCH_ALL,SPH_MATCH_PHRASE,SPH_MATCH_BOOLEAN,SPH_MATCH_ALL and SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2?

   <?php
 include('sphinxapi.php');
        $cl = new SphinxClient();
        $cl->SetServer('localhost',9312);
            $cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
        //$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
        //$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ALL);
        //$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_PHRASE);
        $cl->SetArrayResult(true);
        $cl->SetLimits(0, 100); 
        $result = $cl->Query("&name Bormis","abc_index");

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result);
        exit;
     ?>
```

In this code here working only SPH_MATCH_ANY.

But, I need with search exist word match.and

How to use all the  Matchind modes in this example?

Answer (score 1):

first choose you [matching mode](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#matching-modes), they all work in different ways. Depending on your application, you'll make your choice.

Sphinx uses some query operators like **&** (and), **|** (or), etc. so if you send a query like `"&name Bormis"`, sphinx might not understand it.

Try using only "Bormis" as a query too see the difference between the matching modes. If you prefer it, you could also do the [search in the command line](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#ref-search) to test if your configuration is correct.

Good Luck!

Comment: ok it's fine.i still confusion.  where exactly  used these matching modes?